# Phone on, No Display

Tags: screen, boot

So my aunt told me to fix her android phone and here's the problem. After the android logo and text splash screen during the boot up, the screen is all black but I can still open applications ( just by randomly tapping the screen ) and I know they work.

Is it a hardware related problem?

Comment: I don't think it's a hardware problem at all, if you can see the splash screen. Maybe there's something wrong with the firmware. Maybe you could do a Factory Reset, or re-flash the custom ROM.

Comment: Dont rule out a corruption on the proximity sensor value.

Comment: At what point does the screen go black? There should be a bootloader screen, then your boot animation, then a screen that states Android files are getting ready with a rotating circle, then your home screen should load. If after boot animation, you'll be able to get in and be able to see recovery to do a factory reset. Clean cache and dalvik cache first and reboot, see if that fixes it before reset---- first try to put a bright light over the proximity sensor and see if the screen becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to flash stock rom in your device , the working of applications ensures that your device is not bricked.You might not be able to boot your phone in recovery mode which will not allow you to Factory Reset(you woun't see any content displayed due to splash screen) so you need to flash stock rom by third party applications from PC such as SP Flashtools,Odin,etc according to your device.

Comment: Perhaps some application turned down your screen brightness for everything.  If you have a widget to change the screen brightness you may know where that button on the home screen panels is located and can turn brightness way up until you remember what was done.  I notice a long press on an unfilled up panel on home screen will bring up a menu where the white background is really white, so if you can read that you might be able to get further help somehow from that knowledge.  I had a browser app that blackened just  itself and had to clear out all data just for that app.

Comment: @dmcritchie the long press on home screen will only show a white background if your theme allows it, otherwise like my theme its black.